# Is it OK to show my research and teaching statements with other faculty before applying?

Tags: application, job-search

I keep thinking there might be something wrong with my research and/or teaching statements because my applications are unsuccessful. If faculty can give critical feedback *before* I apply, that can help me feel less of a sense that I fell into a *hidden trap* that is causing my application to not win the application game.

For more clarification, I have started to think of academia as being a giant mine. There are hidden traps and bombs all over the place. Some people are told by experienced people where the bombs are. They get a leg up and are playing on easy mode. Some are playing the game (the end game of which is to get tenure) on the hardest difficulty level, where they are given no hints.

Thus, I got an email about a panel where grad students can learn the "secrets" to a successful job application. The secrets are to know how to avoid the hidden traps.

Comment: Of course you can, why not show it to your PhD/postdoc advisor?

Comment: Well I did. But he is more familiar with me. I want feedback from someone who is unfamiliar with my work, because that will be most people on the committee.

Comment: When you say "other faculty" do you mean at the institution where you're applying, or in a broad sense?

Comment: @AnonymousM - no, I was thinking about faculty I know. Like, the people writing recommendation letters for me

Comment: The truth is that there are significantly more total applicants than total jobs.  A significant fraction of people on the job market will never get a job simply by the Pigeonhole Principle.  Many of the people who do not get a job are not doing anything wrong.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Well, I need all the help I can get.

Comment: I am saying this to point out your situation is entirely normal, not to discourage you: as far as I can tell, in the entire history of the math PhD program at my university (which is older than me), no one earning a PhD in pure math has ever gone on to a research-oriented postdoctoral position (though a small number have gotten offers they had to turn down for personal reasons).  It's very rare for people who don't get admitted to higher-ranking programs to have the necessary talent, and being in a department where high-powered research by other graduate students is nonexistent doesn't help.

Comment: Do by all means get feedback on your statements, but by far the most likely answer is that there is nothing wrong with them that you can fix (and I have reviewed a fair number of statements).

Comment: @AlexanderWoo: I think that's sort of what the PhD program I was at used to be (and still kind of is) but now they've made changes to really try to improve the situation.

Comment: Just in case you are have different expectations: a fairly successful research group I'm happy to be a part of gets probably about 15-20% of their grant applications supported. A more typical number would be some 10%, I believe, and that is for relatively strong applications involving people with established track record. There are often small programs aimed to give that much-needed boost to those at the start of their careers, and often it is much like "working for exposure": not enough funding to reasonably cover expenses, but your next application would be stronger.

Answer (score 8):

It is common practice to ask people for feed-back on these types of documents. There are even institutions where any official letter is supposed to be proof-read by another person just to avoid grammar and spelling mistakes. So much more reason to subject something as difficult to write as teaching and research statements to helpful criticism.

The institutions to which you apply cannot give you this feedback. Interacting with a rejected applicant will open them up to potential legal problems or invite discussions that are pointless because hiring decisions cannot be revisited. The same goes for people working there as there answering could be construed as acting in an official capacity.

The more familiar people are with the processes of academia, the more their feedback is useful. The more familiar they are with you, the more their feedback is useful, because you might be unconsciously misrepresenting yourself.